# Search in ArrayDataProvider list in YII2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I used below code to generate list in yii2

Controler code

```
$data = [['id'=>1, 'name'=>'name1'],
['id'=>2, 'name'=>'name2'],
['id'=>3, 'name'=>'name3'],
['id'=>4, 'name'=>'name4'],
['id'=>5, 'name'=>'name5'],
['id'=>6, 'name'=>'name6'],]
$provider = new ArrayDataProvider([
            'allModels' => $data,
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 5,
            ],
            'sort' => [
                'attributes' => ['id', 'name'],
            ],
        ]);
$lists = $provider->getModels();
return $this->render('list', [                
                'provider'  => $provider,
                'lists'  => $lists,              
            ]);
```

View code

```
foreach($lists as $list){
.....
}
```

Pagination

```
\yii\widgets\LinkPager::widget([
    'pagination'=>$provider->pagination,
]);
```

This code is working but i need search or filter option in this list
like name ='name2' search

I am new for yii2 framework Please suggest any suitable solution for this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

ArrayDataProvider implement sort only. You have 2 choice:

1. Fitler data before creating dataProvider
2. Extend ArrayDataProvider and implement filters.